# Flutter/Dart - exception on URL that doesn't Exist anywhere in the project?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I'm using Android Studio and getting an error on a NetworkImage url which doesn't exist anywhere in the project. I've done a "Find in Path" (control shift F) from the top of the project and the URL doesn't appear anywhere. I'm utterly baffled. I recognize the URL from a site which I migrated away from. But I've replaced every single URL in the project so I don't know where it's coming from. Where could it be?

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed host lookup: 'app.myurl.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://app.myurl.com/63-user.jpg?v=1603283280800", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://app.myurl.com/63-user.jpg?v=1603283280800", scale: 1.0)
```

Comment: Could you search in your code, if you are using `NetworkImage()` anywhere. If so try commenting them out and see if the error still persists

Comment: That's the first thing I did. Turns out I had to delete the build folder.  For some reason "Flutter clean" wasn't deleting it. But I'll accept Sergey Metelins answer as Flutter Clean should've deleted the build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `flutter clean` to clean the build cache.

Comment: That was worth a shot but unfortunately didn't work...